# When did the practice of exiting-reentering during applause in classical concerts start?

Tags: performing, classical-music, history

As the title suggests, I'm looking for some information on when the practice (concerning soloists and directors) of exiting and reentering the stage during an applause after a classical performance started. I have tried searching on the web, but to no avail. There seem to be many articles and general documentation on why we don't clap in between movements (a rule I personally find abhorrent) but none on this end-of-concert practice.

I can see that ego of the performer and/or director is showered with renewed applause is this way, but was there a period in which this coming in and out started being mainstream?

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? The question seems to me pretty precise, not off topic, and conformant to guidelines.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd surmize that it followed the curtain-call practice of stage plays.

Comment: Ah good intuition! I'll check out more on that and eventually post an answer myself if I find something

Comment: Spelling in the title: reeintering! As to the downvotes, perhaps someone was (somewhat unreasonably) upset by your opinion on clapping between movements (surely depends if people want to maintain a rapt mood) or by a sense that you grudge the performers their bath in applause.

Comment: @PJTraill thanks for pointing out the typo! Edited. As for the downvotes, if that's the case, I'm relieved to know that they were breaking site rules and I wasn't

Answer (score 1):

You have to be good and confident to leave and return during applause! What if you were not so good? It does create a renewed wave of appreciation from the audience and if a singer has planned an encore they can grab a quick drink and mentally rehearse it. Accompanists can set up the encore music.

Comment: Sure, I don't question that it has its advantage/purpose. I was just wondering if it has always been like this (unlike no clapping between movements, which is known to not have always been this way)